# Only looking to existing variables

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, hashtable

Question i am going to ask will be very specific.

Lets say we have an array/hash table which have a certain size.
And not every space in this array/table is used.
For example lets say we have an integer array named "arr" which size of 150.

```
arr[3] = 5;
arr[16] = 22;
arr[127] = 3;
```

and except this three, all other spaces between 0 and 150 is null.
and now lets say we want print every number in this array (which is not null).

We can make a loop that from 0 to 150 which check if array space is null, if not then print it.
But thats mean for just printing 3 variable we need to make 150 checking.

The thing i wonder is if its possible to directly print this numbers without looking the whole array.
I mean instead of checking nulls, direcly going from one not-null variable to another not-null variable.

Also my question same in hash table, lets say we didnt create table for every number between 0 and hash table size. Is it possible to look only existing tables instead of cheching if table is exist or not every single time.

Even if its impossbile to do what i am saying with array or hash table, is there any method which directly go from one variable to the next one. (Linked list is not what i am searching)

Comment: There is no such thing as a `null` `int` in C#. Do you mean they are `int?` type?

Comment: Use a `List<int>` and just add items to it when you need to. It's a basically a resizable array.

Comment: I would use a `Dictionary<int, int>` instead of an array here. You can use  the methods of the dictionary to just get existing keys (keys would be the array indicies).

Comment: Is this C++ or C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array is a Fixed Size -- Continuous Memory Data Structure. There is no way of knowing which element is assigned & which isn't (without either remembering the assigned indexes separately or iteration).

HashTable (or Dictionary) -- is not a Continuous Memory Structure. In my opinion only 3 entries should (ideally) be stored in the HashTable. You would not store other (Null) items at all. You can do the same with List.

If For some reason you add everything from 0 to 150 to HashTable with the values for all except these 3 being Null. Again you don't have any simpler way but iteration to figure that out.